# Alternative Young tabloid shape

Tags: diagrams, tabularx, ytableau

Hi I'm trying to draw a young tabloid exactly as it's shown in the following picture: 
Here is my attempt but I could not make the boundaries of each row (I need to close each row). Could you please help me.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{ytableau}
 \begin{document}
  \ytableausetup{tabloids,centertableaux}
  $\ytableaushort{2359,687,\vdots,1}$
  \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I do not think that this can be achieved by a simple option in ytableau, but very easily with a tabular or so. Hence I am wondering if you would also consider a solution not based on ytableau.

Comment: This is what I guessed. I thought that might also be drawn using tableau package.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this you do not need any of the tableau packages, I think.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,array}
\usepackage{ytableau}
\begin{document}
  \ytableausetup{tabloids,centertableaux}
  $\ytableaushort{2359,687,\vdots,1}$
  ~~~~~
  $\begin{array}{|>{\vphantom{\big|_0^0}}cccc|}
  \hline
  2&3&5&9\\
  \hline
  6&8&7&\multicolumn{1}{|c}{~}\\
  \cline{1-3}
  \makebox[0pt][c]{\vdots}& \multicolumn{3}{|c}{~} \\
  \cline{1-1}
  1& \multicolumn{3}{|c}{~}\\
  \cline{1-1}
  \end{array}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Marmot for your response but I don't need the rows to be separated by columns as appears in the second diagram. I need it as the uploaded picture in the inquiry.

Comment: @MalJA Oh, sorry. This is even simpler.

Comment: You are always supportive. Just little concern, how to alter the third row to be wider than the last row.

Comment: Many thanks for all your suggestion and help